# Method dispatch using R via S4 setMethod(): single numerical element vs numerical vector

Tags: r, vector, methods, overloading, r-s4

I am trying to use `S4` generic methods and call the right method based on the signature of the object that is being passed.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
setGeneric(
    name = "_get_prob_2pl",
    def = function(discrimination, difficulty, theta) {
        standardGeneric("_get_prob_2pl")
    })



# # case 1 
setMethod(
    f = "_get_prob_2pl",
    signature = "numeric", # also tried "double" and "integer"
    definition = function(discrimination, difficulty, theta) 
    {
        x = exp(1) ^ (discrimination * (theta - difficulty)) 
        return(x / (1 + x))
    })



# # case 2
setMethod(
    f = "_get_prob_2pl",
    signature = "vector",
    definition = function(discrimination, difficulty, theta) 
    {
        if(length(discrimination) == length(difficulty)) {  
            responses <- NULL
            temp_respondent_row <- NULL

            for(i in 1:length(theta)) 
            {
                for(j in 1:length(discrimination)) 
                {   
                    temp_respondent_row[j] = get_prob_2pl(discrimination[j], difficulty[j], theta[i])
                }

                responses <- rbind(responses, temp_respondent_row)
            }
            rownames(responses) <- NULL
            return(responses)

        } else {    
            stop("The length of vectors 'discrimination' and 'difficulty' must be equal, Their length give the number of items.")  
        }
    })
```

Specifically, the issues is that I can't differentiate between two use cases:

- in the first case, I want to pass just single numerical elements e.g., `discrimination = 1.5`, `difficulty = 2`, `theta = 0.98`.
- in the second case I want to pass numerical vectors e.g., `discrimination = c(1.5, 1.7, 1.9)`, `difficulty = c(1.5, 2, 3.5)`, `theta = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 etc.)`

I tried to explore different types, but it seems that `R` stores single elements as one-element vectors.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- 1.5

typeof(x) # double
typeof(y) # double


is.vector(x) # TRUE
is.vector(y) # TRUE

is.double(x) # TRUE
is.double(y) # TRUE

is.integer(x) # FALSE
is.integer(y) # FALSE
```

Do you have any idea how can I get out of this situation?

Comment: In R there's no concept of scalar value, so yes `1.5` is a vector of length 1

Comment: "R stores single elements as one-element vectors" [Yes, it does](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Vector-objects). "Do you have any idea how can I get out of this situation?" `if (length(x) == 1L)`?

Comment: Maybe you could test for the length of the numeric and if it is more than 1 you could use `nextMethod` to send in onto the vector signature.

Comment: @Roland I need to do it in the `signature = "something_here"` parameter from the `setClass()` function. Not sure I can perform logical testing there?

Comment: @JohnPaul Can you detail a bit more? I appreciate it.

Comment: At the top of the body of the `numeric` method try putting `if (length(x) == 1L) NextMethod()` . Not sure if that will work, but worth a try.

Comment: @JohnPaul Giving it a try now. Will write back in a second.

Comment: @JohnPaul I placed in the body of the case two method and it didn't work. It uses the case one body.

Comment: Length-one vectors don't have a particular class and thus you can't apply a particular method to them. However, you should not need this. Just use the `if` condition in your method if you really need specific handling of length-one vectors. But why would you? In your example you certainly don't. `for (i in 1)` works just fine. PS: I don't think `"vector"` is a class. PPS: And of course, I would replace your loop with a vectorized approach.

Comment: @Roland I think you'll right. Will do it this way. I was wondering whether there is a possibly to do it via `signature`, but I can live without it for know! Thanks!

Comment: @Roland Can you please give me some insight into how to replace this with a vectorized operation? I'm really intrigued!

Comment: It depends on how big you expect the input vectors to be. If they are not too large you could use `exp(outer(discrimination, theta - difficulty, "*"))`. If they are large, you'd be better of with an Rcpp solution. Post a new question if you need further help with vectorization.

Comment: Thanks @Roland. I don't expect to have more than 250 on `discrimination`, but the vector `thetas` will get close to 10k. I will try what you said. I made a post about it on `Code Review`. If you can take a look, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks for your suggestion & for pointing me at something new to learn! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/155962/98406?stw=2

Comment: 2.5 million values should still fit in RAM comfortably, so `outer` should be fine.